# поменять каждую строку массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть массив

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

как сделать на выходе массив

```
[30, 10, 11, 100, 500] # это пример
```

т.е мне нужно заменить элементы массива другими элементами (вообще в программе будут строки)

например из m = ['я', 'самый', 'голодный', 'в', 'мире'] превратить в res = ['а', 'тбньк', 'дпмпеоьк', 'г', 'нйсё'] имеется ввиду пройти по каждому элементу списка m, а далее по каждой букве каждого элемента из списка m, а позже поменять каждую букву по словарю так чтобы получился массив res (столько же индексов). Тут использовался шифр цезаря, на его примере я рассказал, что нужно вообще. На деле будет использовать другой шифр

Пусть словарь будет таков:

```
SHIEF_DICT = {
'а': 11111, 'б': 222220, 'в': 33330, 'г': 444480,
'д': 55550, 'е': 66660, 'ё': 77777, 'ж': 88888,
'з': 9999999, 'и': 100000, 'й': 11111, 'к': 1343,
'л': 113251, 'м': 214261, 'н': 315271, 'о': 3434341,
'п': 517291, 'р': 618301, 'с': 7566411, 'т': 854542,
'у': 9213345131, 'ф': 10345221, 'х': 1153341, 'ц': 123425431,
'ч': 113252, 'ш': 4334343, 'щ': 343452, 'ъ': 4423423,
'ы': 53434345, 'ь': 4343421, 'э': 745422, 'ю': 832434,
'я': 34325435
}

вообще я реализовал дешифратор, но дешифрует он лишь одно слово (я подумал, почему не использовать массивы)
```

Comment: В чем проблема?

Comment: `res = [30, 10, 11, 100, 500]` ;)

Comment: @Shamus Rezol, Прошу прощения я имел ввиду:
например из m = ['я', 'самый', 'голодный', 'в', 'мире']
превратить в res = ['а', 'тбньк', 'дпмпеоьк', 'г', 'нйсё']
имеется ввиду пройти по каждому элементу списка m, а далее по каждой букве каждого элемента из списка m, а позже поменять каждую букву по словарю так чтобы получился массив res (столько же индексов). Сейчас поправлю свой вопрос на то, что я написал в уточнении...

Comment: @MaxU, это гениально, но не то, что мне нужно. Я дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: @XXX, каков вопрос, таков ответ ;) Вы можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных, словарь замены и результат, который хотите получить ?

Comment: может вам воспользоваться  chr()/ord() ?

Answer (score 3):

Шаги решения:

1. пишем функцию (например `my_func()`), заменяющую буквы в одной строке, используя словарь замены или ключ шифра
2. вызываем функцию для каждой строки из списка и получаем список зашифрованных строк:

```
res = [my_func(x) for x in m]
```